# Customize the different colors of files, folders, binaries in the ouput of ls command in zsh/MacOS

Tags: macos, zsh, syntax-highlighting, ls

I just switched to `zsh` from `bash` on my MacOS 10.14.6 and want to know how to have the output of content of folder (e.g.. when typing `ls` command) in different color

For example if I type

```
[mymac@Documents]$ls
Folder1
File1.txt
@stuff
```

I would like the 3 output items to be in 3 different colors. How can I edit the `.zshrc` file accordingly?

**EDIT**

I tried the following command with the corresponding error output:

```
$ ls --color=auto
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

The same happend with `$ alias ls='ls --color=always'`

It worked with the following command but the color of the folders are dark blue and hence very difficult to read.

```
alias ls='ls -G'
```

I also saw those 2 other links but it didn't help:
[SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/665274/how-to-make-ls-color-its-output-by-default-without-setting-up-an-alias)

Is there a way of manually define the colors?

**EDIT 2**
I found this piece of code that worked for me (from [there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/how-can-i-configure-mac-terminal-to-have-color-ls-output))

```
COLOR_RED="\033[0;31m"
COLOR_YELLOW="\033[0;33m"
COLOR_GREEN="\033[0;32m"
COLOR_OCHRE="\033[38;5;95m"
COLOR_BLUE="\033[0;34m"
COLOR_WHITE="\033[0;37m"
COLOR_RESET="\033[0m"

#git_color
function git_color {
  local git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"

  if [[ ! $git_status =~ "working directory clean" ]]; then
    echo -e $COLOR_RED
  elif [[ $git_status =~ "Your branch is ahead of" ]]; then
    echo -e $COLOR_YELLOW
  elif [[ $git_status =~ "nothing to commit" ]]; then
    echo -e $COLOR_GREEN
  else
    echo -e $COLOR_OCHRE
  fi
}

#git_branch
function git_branch {
  local git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
  local on_branch="On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"
  local on_commit="HEAD detached at ([^${IFS}]*)"

  if [[ $git_status =~ $on_branch ]]; then
    local branch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "($branch)"
  elif [[ $git_status =~ $on_commit ]]; then
    local commit=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "($commit)"
  fi
}

#PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]'
#PS1+="\[\$(git_color)\]"        # colors git status
#PS1+="\$(git_branch)"           # prints current branch
#PS1+="\[$COLOR_BLUE\]\[$COLOR_RESET\]\$ "
#export PS1

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
```

Comment: why not use oh-my-zsh?
https://ohmyz.sh/

Comment: you can try `ls -G`  for BSD `ls`

Comment: @Jetchisel you mean `alias ls='ls -G'` instead of `alias ls='ls -GFh'`? If yes, I just tried it and unfortunately it didn't change anything: the folders are still very dark blue and hard to see

Comment: Indeed, that is what the output on my FreeBSD. well not sure how to fix it since  the man pages is pointing to `termcap(5)` and `LSCOLORS `